# Echo all files in sub folders containing a parameter

Tags: batch-file

Just started learning batch files, in search of some help!

I have a folder directory, that contains lots of .exe files. Some of the subfolders contain multiple .exe files and other files as well, like so:

```
Folder 1
    file.exe
    file.conf
    file.exe
Folder 2
    file.exe
Folder 3
    file.txt
    file.exe
Folder 4
    file.exe
```

However, in some of the folders I have multiple .exe files, and I only want to list the `setup.exe` file:

```
Folder 5
    file.exe
    setup.exe
    file2.exe
```

I can list all .exe files in the folder and subfolders using

`for /r %%i in (*.exe*) do echo %%~nxi`

which displays the file name and extension for all the files.

However, is it possible to list .exe files if they contain a value, e.g. only echo the filename if it contains the word `setup`?

Thanks!

Comment: Literally just found that out after I posted this question -.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, literally I found out the answer a minute after I posted the question.

I wanted to find all .exe files containing the word `setup`.

`for /r %%i in (*setup*.exe) do echo %%~nxi`

Comment: 1. you did not mention `T` and `C` in your question, so the related part of the answer does not fit; 2. your filter `*TC*.exe` will find `.exe` files that contain `TC`, `Tc`, `tC` and `tc`; it will _not_ find files containing `ToC`, for example, neither will it find `CT`; 3. `*setup.exe*` will find files like `setup.exe`, `ABCsetup.executable`,..., but will not find `setupABC.exe`; since you said »_echo the filename if it **contains** the word `setup`_« in your question, the correct filter should be like `*setup*.exe`;

Comment: Apologies, I'd been working on the file so I had extra stuff in there without realising, I've edited my answer so it fits the question :)